# Blocking Windows 11 update on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Of course nothing will be certain until October 5, but is there any **recent** information about how to block the Windows 11 update?

There are numerous copy-pasted articles from around July 2021. They all refer to a registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`. That path does not exist on my machine. I have not tinkered with the registry before, and the absence of this path has not prevented Windows Update from running. This gives me doubts about whether creating it and following the instructions will have any effect.

Comment: As per [https://www.ghacks.net/2021/07/06/how-to-block-the-windows-11-update/](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/07/06/how-to-block-the-windows-11-update/) you can just create the key; or use GP Editor to block the upgrade. Export the current registry hive `HKLM\Software` before making registry changes and you can easily restore the pre-change situation.

Comment: @Peregrino69 That article says nothing about creating the `WindowsUpdate` path, just the keys within it. If you think that's the solution, please post an answer to be voted on.

Comment: Well, the registry path is the only applicable path, and registry keys exist or are created within :-) I'd probably try GP Editor first. I'm not keen on posting this as an answer yet, as I've not yet tested and confirmed whether either of the solutions work.

Comment: @Peregrino69 My doubt is whether it's really applicable at all, since its absence hasn't seemed to affect Windows Update.

Comment: Fair doubt :-) As I said, I'd check the GP Editor first. I'll be doing offline backup of my Win10 installation with Clonezilla so I can restore it in case things go south, or if Win11 update forces itself. One article I saw says that if you don't like the upgrade you can roll back within 10 days. I don't get why force an upgrade anyway... W10 should be supported till -25.

Comment: With Windows 7 and 8, I could always say "No" I do not want the update. But I do not always want to be asked.  GWX is / was available to turn on the request in Windows 7. I no longer have Windows 8. Also Microsoft has said updates will not be offered to machines greater than 3 years old. So we have to see what happens at the release point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may disable Windows 11 update with Group Policy Editor:

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Windows Update for Business*
- Double-click the policy "Select the target feature update version"
- Set the policy to "Enabled"
- Type `21H1` into the field
- Close the Group Policy Editor.

The same via the registry:

- Run `regedit.exe`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`
- Right-click "WindowsUpdate", and select "New > Dword (32-bit) Value"
- Name the item `TargetReleaseVersionInfo` and set its value to `21H1`.