# How to cancel ready to install Windows 11 update in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-11-upgrade

Today I just realized MS prepared for me (and almost completed) a Windows 11 installation on my Winsows 10 machine. I don't want this and I'd like to cancel this installation.

Having tried the solution from this question [Blocking Windows 11 update on Windows 10 Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1679441/blocking-windows-11-update-on-windows-10-pro) I realized it doesn't work. I made all the steps like described, set the target goal to 21H2 but nothing changed, I still see this message in the Update Center. Probably because my Windows 11 update process was already started (files were downloaded) and this solution works as **preventive**, i.e. when you want to block not started installation.

[image]

If the Windows 11 upgrade is "Ready to install" is there any way to block it?

Comment: I'm afraid it already downloaded the installer and there's no way to avoid it being installed now.

Comment: this can't be real, this is so nasty practice to make users install Windows 11 silently and without being able to avoid it. I cannot believe MS does this

Comment: worst case, you can just rollback. After it installs on reboot, just go settings > recovery > rollback

Comment: is it officially supported to rollback from Win11 to Win10? I cannot find any offical help how to do this

Comment: One doesn’t receive a Windows Insider Preview build, by seeking, only by signing up which suggests you either have a Windows 10 Insider Preview build or you signed up and because there isn’t an active Insider Preview build you signed up and are offering the current Insider Build

Comment: So try exiting the Insider Preview Program

Comment: @Ramhound Leaving the Windows Insider Program helped, now this message has disappeared and my Update Center is clean again. Add you solution as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the Windows 11 upgrade is "Ready to install" like on screenshot is there any way to block it?

Since the upgrade is to an Insider Preview build, you can simply leave the Insider Preview Program, to stop receiving upgraded Insider Preview builds

Answer (score 4):

It can't be stopped, as far as I know, at this point.

But you can continue with it and then roll back to the previous Windows version (10).
(Settings->Recovery->Rollback)

If you do that straight away after the upgrade there should be no harm done.

Having said that: Double check your Windows Update settings, because this is the Windows 11 Insider Preview which you only get if you enrolled the computer into the Insider program, which is something you absolutely don't want to do if you need to stay on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The update is like most other Windows updates. If the update has been completed to the point of installation, it cannot be cancelled.

You may be able to pause for a couple of days, but ultimately it will install.

Windows has deemed your computer ready for the upgrade, so it should work.

I have had Windows 11 Production running for about 2 years now and it is working reliably.

You can always try rolling back to Windows 10 but then you need to be careful about updates for then on.

I suggest exiting from the Insider Program also.

Comment: Insider Preview cannot be "working reliably", it wasn't even released

Comment: It should not be Insider coming from Windows 10 . It will be production. But I see you must have the Insider program running.

Comment: Either way there's no reason to downvote this answer!

Comment: Production is working fine and most Insider versions are fine with minor issues.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Even if the upgrade can be cancelled?

Comment: @Ramhound Unlike many of his other answers and anoying comments this one isn't that bad.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - No Comment