# Windows 11 Preview install fails on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v, windows-11-preview

I want to test some new features of Windows 11 (how [the bugs were fixed](https://www.windowslatest.com/2023/03/16/windows-11s-never-combine-taskbar-icons-feature-is-coming-in-the-fall/#:%7E:text=The%20feature%20is%20called%20the,be%20grouped%20under%20one%20icon.)) and want to install the [latest preview build](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/09/13/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-23545-dev-channel/) in Hyper-V playground.

It fails with the following message

[image]

The Hyper-V VM is created in quick mode (Action-Quick Create) and then I select "_Local installation source" and feeding the Win11 Preview ISO to hypervisor

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Any particular VM setting to check?

Hyper-V: 10.0.19041.3086 
Windows 11: Windows11_InsiderPreview_Client_x64_en-us_23545.iso

**UPDATE** screenshots of the VM definition are in this album
https://imgur.com/a/tLqpz03
This definition is created by the "Quick Create" wizard

Comment: If the host computer doesn't has all the requirements to run Windows 11 then you can't use as VM either. If it does then it's up to the virtualization solution to provide the same requirements including UEFI boot and TPM. Check those before anything else and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Windows 11 should install if the Host is using UEFI, has Secure Boot, and has TPM V2.  If not, there is a flag (registry setting) you can use to get around the installation requirements.

Comment: `If the host computer doesn't has all the requirements to run Windows 11` it does, check my other question https://superuser.com/questions/1810417/how-to-cancel-already-planned-windows-11-update-in-win10-pro?noredirect=1#comment2842734_1810417. MS pushes me to upgrade, that is why it I want to test smth before the upgrade

Comment: `if the Host is using UEFI, has Secure Boot, and has TPM V2` yes, and yes, and yes, I just checked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Again, check VMware settings for the VM you're trying to deploy. They must match the requirements the same way a bare metal installation has. There's no magic in this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/86207

Comment: Try using the complete installation routine and not quick action.  It will need to be a Generation 2 machine

Comment: @John It's a little more complicated than that, please read the VMware article above.

Comment: The steps for Hyper-V install are reasonably straightforward to follow

Comment: I never had any problem installing Windows 11 in a Hyper-V VM. Please share screenshots of the definition of your VM.

Comment: `Again, check VMware settings for the VM you're trying to deploy` I'm using the Hyper-V, not VMWare, you missed the question title

Comment: @harrymc, `Please share screenshots of the definition of your VM` added to the question body, please check

Comment: `Try using the complete installation routine and not quick action. It will need to be a Generation 2 machine` just created with the full-featured Wizard and explicitly selected Gen 2, same result. Fail.

Comment: I am not sure why the full featured install should fail if the host has all the required attributes.  I will keep looking around

Comment: might be related with the Preview and its new features. I have no possibility to test Hyper-V built-in Win11 Dev Env showed on the screesnhot and dunno which version it downloads, as it starts downloading 24Gb image, much more than I have

Comment: Have you tried installing using the Windows Media Creation Tool to download an ISO that you mount and boot the VM to?

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot but also TPM support. Research on how to enable UEFI boot for Hyper-V VMs. Make sure the VM is Generation 2

Comment: `Have you tried installing using the Windows Media Creation Tool to download an ISO that you mount and boot the VM to` just tried, the same result. Fail.

Comment: `Windows 11 requires Secure Boot but also TPM support. Research on how to enable UEFI boot for Hyper-V VMs. Make sure the VM is Generation 2` yes, I select Gen2 and SecureBoot is enabled by default on Gen2 VMs, you can see 'enables Windows Secure Boot" checkbox on my screenshots, this is checked by default on VM quick create and I don't change this setting while creating the VM